# C++ Qt - Check if a steam game is running or not programmatically

Tags: c++, windows, qt, registry, steam

I wanted to know if there is a way to check if a steam game is running or not programatically, knowing its steamid, on Windows.
I know about the fact that each game has its registry key in which there is a Running value.
However, this value doesn't seem to work for all games. For example, it works for me for Undertale : it updates instantly both on opening and closure. The issue is Rocket League running value doesn't change at opening. I don't know if this issue happens for other games, or if it's only happening with Rocket League, but the solution doesn't seem to be good enough in this case.

The reason I ask this is because running the game from an external program only retrieves steam.exe process id and not the actual game process id so I'm stuck to checking manually.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure that the value does not change for Rocket League? Maybe you need the game in the foreground, did you look up the value manually or logged it?

Comment: Yeah I'm sure. The game was on fullscreen though but I doubt that would change its state. I checked the value manually each time, but my software actually logs it and it never changed to Running for 2 minutes (I didn't try further than 2 minutes though).

Comment: Apparently it does go running but only for one second (before the window pops up)

Comment: Is `Rocket League` a steam game or an external game?

Comment: It is a steam game, and I found a better way to track steam games running, I'll answer my question in a few minutes if you are interested.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For people who are wondering, I found a solution.
At `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Valve\Steam` there is a `RunningAppID` value which will take the currently running game steamid as value. This one has been 100% reliable until now for me so I believe it's the solution I was seeking for.
Hopefully it helps you too.

Comment: Is there anoter way, for example, by running some command with parameters, like `steam --currently-running`? I ask because I want it on linux. I also tried to do it with registry, because currently I need it for game that is running under proton. I have found this topic https://www.reddit.com/r/linux_gaming/comments/9ar9ru/how_do_i_access_the_registry_editor_in_proton/ but seems like proton registry does not have such key as you named.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are looking for VR applications (which are masked by SteamVR), try enumerating `HKCU\SOFTWARE\Value\Steam\Apps`. Each entry contains a `Running` key indicating if the corresponding application is running.